# child element state passed as props does not get updated after updating state from parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-state, react-beautiful-dnd

so I was trying to make a Kanban board app like a clone to trello by using react-beautiful-dnd, everything is fine except that when I change the state of the draggable element which is a child of droppable element, the UI data doesn't change despite the state change in main app, and I was passing the data to draggable as props from the droppable and updating the state from the droppable.

below is the file structure and code.

[image: File structure]

```js
App.jsx
```

```js
import './App.css'
import List from './components/List'
import Form from './components/Form'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

function App() {

  const [listData, setListData] = useState(["some sample data"])

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { source, destination } = result;

    const data = structuredClone(listData);
    if (!destination) return;

    if (destination.droppableId == source.droppableId) {
      if (destination.index == source.index) {
        return;
      } else {
        //logic to update state
        return;
      }
    } else {
      //logic to update state
      })
      setListData(data)
      console.log(listData)
      return;
    }
  }

  const addTodo = (todo) => {
    const data = structuredClone(listData);
    data[0].todos.push(todo)
    setListData(data)
  }


  return (
    <div className='app' id='root'>
      <h1>KenBoards</h1>
      <Form addTodo={addTodo} />
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <div className="lists">
          {listData.map((element, index) => <List
            key={index}
            title={element.title}
            todos={element.todos}
            setListData={setListData}
          />)}
        </div>
      </DragDropContext >
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```js
List.jsx
```

```js
import Todo from './Todo';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

import styles from '../styles/list.module.css';

const List = ({ title, todos, setListData }) => {


    const changeTodo = (changedTodo) => {

        const changingTodo = (prev) => {
            let indexOfList = prev.findIndex(i => i.title == title);
            let indexOfTodo = prev[indexOfList].todos.findIndex(i => i.id == changedTodo.id)
            prev[indexOfList].todos.splice(indexOfTodo, 1, changedTodo)
            return prev
        }
        setListData(prev => changingTodo(prev))

    }

    return <Droppable droppableId={title} >
        {(provided) => (
            <div className={styles.list} ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
                <h4 className={styles.title}>{title}</h4>
                {todos.map((element, index) => (
                    <Todo
                        key={element.id}
                        index={index}
                        id={element.id}
                        name={element.name}
                        description={element.description}
                        changeTodo={changeTodo}
                    />
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
        )}

    </Droppable>
}

export default List
```

```js
Todo.jsx
```

```js
import { useState } from 'react'


import styles from '../styles/todo.module.css';
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

const Todo = ({ id, index, name, description, changeTodo }) => {

    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false)

    const [newName, setNewName] = useState(name)
    const [newDesc, setNewDesc] = useState(description)

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        changeTodo({ id, newName, newDesc })
        setEditing(false)
    }

    return (<div>
        <Draggable draggableId={id.toString()} index={index}>
            {(provided) => (
                !editing ? <>
                    <div className={styles.todo}
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                        <div className={styles.todo_name}>{newName}</div>
                        <div className={styles.todo_description}>{newDesc}</div>
                    </div>
                    <span onClick={() => setEditing(true)}>edit</span>
                </> : <>
                    <form action="" id='todoForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                        <div className={styles.form} >
                            <div className={styles.fields}>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder='Name' value={newName} onChange={e => setNewName(e.target.value)} />
                                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder='Description' value={newDesc} maxLength={40} onChange={e => setNewDesc(e.target.value)} />
                                <span>Max Length : 50 characters only</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles.submit}>
                                <button className={styles.button} type="submit">Add Todo</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Todo
```

by the end of the changeTodo function the state is successfully changed as I checked the value of state by logging it to the console. but the content of the todo element are not changed.

I'll be grateful if someone can help me. Also I could use any suggestions if I'm following any anti-patterns here in the code. Thanks in advance.